# Unable able to load sos in WnDbg

Tags: c#

Operating Used : Windows xp 64Bit
C# Application Built with configuration: Any CPU
Wndbg Used : 6.12
.net version : 3.5

When I attach the Wndbg and type the command .load sos getting the following error
The call to LoadLibrary(sos) failed, Win32 error 0n193
    "%1 is not a valid Win32 application."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.

I wanted to know what does Any CPU means - does it create a 64Bit or 32 bit exe and is there any change in the command to load SOS

Comment: I've always used `.loadby sos mscorwks`, rather than `.load sos`

Comment: It sounds like your WinDbg mismatches the application. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373683 for more.

Answer (score 0):

"Any CPU" means that when the program is started, the .NET Framework will figure out, based on the OS bitness, whether to run your program in 32 bits or 64 bits."

Concerning loading the correct version of SOS use the following command depending on the .NET version.

**.NET 4 and higher** *.loadby sos*

**.NET 3.5 and 2**
*.loadby sos mscorwks*

**.NET 1.0 and 1.1**
*.load clr10\sos*