# visual studio 2015 debug command

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have some problems with the debug command in visual studio 2015 professional. I have a limited access to debugger command. For example, commands like dc, db, ~ are working while lm, ld are not and also the extended commands like .dump, .ecxr.
My visual studio is running on Windows 7. I am using the command window when the debugger has reach a breakpoint. I don't see what could go wrong.
Any help appreciate ...

Comment: My understanding is that you use the Windows debugging(Windbg) command line, do you use the VS Debugger Immediate Window? My understanding is that not all command lines are supported in VS Immediate window now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926920/cannot-use-windbg-and-sos-in-visual-studio-immediate-window

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you. I've installed windbg standalone to be able to use extra command.

Comment: Using the Windbg directly with the command lines would be better, anyway, glad to know that you get the solution. The answer was similar to the link in my previous comment, but I think they were different questions like different VS versions or other MSFT tools or command lines. I just post the comment as the answer, if possible, you could mark it as the answer, and then we could close this case. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all Windbg command lines are supported in VS IDE, so if you really want to use those command line like .dump, .ecxr or others, using the single WinDbg tool would be better.