# WinDbg fails to load SOS.dll

Tags: windbg

I need to debug a 32-bit managed application using WinDbg, however WinDbg stubbornly refuses to load the SOS.dll extension.  After many Internet searches and things tried I'm stumped.  I have experience debugging unmanaged code with WinDbg but this is my first attempt with managed.

When I direct WinDbg to load the default SOS.dll it gives this error:

```
sxe ld clr                <- I wait until the clr has loaded
.loadby sos clr

The call to LoadLibrary(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos) failed,     Win32 error 0n193
    "%1 is not a valid Win32 application."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.
```

And if I instead attempt to specify the SOS.dll I receive a different error:

```
.load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos clr

The call to LoadLibrary(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos clr) failed, Win32 error 0n126
    "The specified module could not be found."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.
```

My setup is VM-to-VM over serial connection and both VMs are  Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.
Debugging Tools For Windows (x64) is installed in both VMs.

**NOTE:**  It appears installing x86 Debugging Tools on a x64 CPU as is suggested in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373683/unable-to-load-sos-in-windbg) is not possible (nor necessary) in newer Windows OS's so please don't suggest it.  The installer fails with an error.

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: what error message? i have seen plenty of x86 windbg installs on win7 64bit

Comment: `.load` only takes the path to SOS, not `clr` at the end. If the x86 installer fails, please re-download. The x86 version and it is needed here, because you can't load a 32 bit DLL into a 64 bit process.

Comment: `My setup is VM-to-VM over serial connection`. Why two VMs? Are you set up for kernel debugging?

Comment: Note that the "specified module could not be found" is due to lack of escaping in the path, Doubling the backslashes gives the same "not a valid Win32 application" error as before.

Answer (score 20):

It is possible to install both x86 and x64 version of WinDbg on the same machine, and if you're debugging a 32 bit .NET app you should use the x86 version of WinDbg/SOS. The error message is telling you that you're trying to load the wrong version of SOS for the bitness of the application.

There's some additional [guidance here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 12):

By default, the installer seems to put both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of WinDbg on the system without prompting - is it possible that you're running the wrong one?

Look in for an "x86" directory in the directory where WinDbg installed, and run the version of windbg.exe contained there.